# CLion - Where is my output?

Tags: c, clion

I recently started to use CLion for my C-Projects. I just wrote a simple program, which writes stuff into a file called *output.txt*, but after executing the program I could not find the output-file.

I went into the Terminal, compiled and executed the program via the command line. Everything works fine there and the *output.txt* file appears.

So my question is, where CLion stored the executables and where the output files. Normally the output can be found in the same directory as the executable, but the executable seems to be located somewhere else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CLion uses a separate directory for building and uses that as the "current directory" when running your programs.

For me working on a Linux system the directory is `~/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/project-name-<digits>`.

If you want another directory, like your actual project directory, then I suggest you edit the "Run/Debug Configurations" for the program, and explicitly set the "Working directory" to the directory you want.

See [Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html?origin=old_help) for more information.

Comment: Thank you really much for the quick answer. Working like a charm :)